# Format a big number like 2182869 to 2.1E8

Tags: python, string, formatting

How do I use the % formatter in Python to format a large number into something like 2.1E8 or 3.2E10?

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to format 2182869 as 2.2E8 (easy) or as 2.1E8 (harder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the e-format type like this:

```
'%.1E' % 2182869
```

Comment: Or `format(2182869, '.1E')` if that's the only value being formatted... It's going to be forcing a loss of precision though... so might be the OP just wants `E` as the format string...

Comment: Yes, but the OP wanted 2.1E8. Probably just a slip of the tongue.

Answer (score 0):

`%e` formatting can be used for this:

```
myint = 2334566778899

>>> print("%1.2e"%myint)
2.33e+12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(format(1234.56789, "10.2E"))
```